# Wall colliders getting out of screen unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, screen-resolution, collider

Basically im developing a 2d pang game style for mobile, where you pop some balls. So i created some walls colliders, but everytime i change the resolution, the left and right walls just dont stick to the right place, or they move out of screen or they move in the screen depending on the resolution. I used them to act as boundaries for the bouncing balls. I have struggle with some many scripts, to try to fit the objects on the screen but i cant find a solution for this. I found similar issues, but there solutions unfortunatilly didnt work :/

Any ideias?

Thank you for all the help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need are `Screen.currentResolution` and `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint()`. This could make things easier. You can adjust the borders position and scale to match your screen before runtime or after changing screen resolution. Visit [unity document](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.html) to see more details.